# Google minimum cost flows to solve transportation flow

Tags: c#, algorithm, linear-programming

Lets say we have the following data to solve transportation problem:

```
          A1      A2      A3      Supply
T1        0       600     100     700
T2        500     0       300     800
Demand    500     600     400
```

I want to solve that transportation problem using Google Optimization Tools Minimum Cost Flows. I'm trying to solve that with the following code:

```
    private static void SolveMinCostFlow()
    {
        // Define four parallel arrays: sources, destinations, capacities, and unit costs
        // between each pair. For instance, the arc from node 0 to node 1 has a
        // capacity of 15.
        // Problem taken From Taha's 'Introduction to Operations Research',
        // example 6.4-2.

        int numNodes = 5;
        int numArcs = 6;
        int[] startNodes = { 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1 };
        int[] endNodes = { 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4};
        int[] capacities = { 500, 600, 400, 500, 600, 400 };
        int[] unitCosts = { 0, 600, 100, 500, 0, 300 };

        // Define an array of supplies at each node.

        int[] supplies = { 700, 700, 800, 800, 800 };



        // Instantiate a SimpleMinCostFlow solver.
        MinCostFlow minCostFlow = new MinCostFlow();

        // Add each arc.
        for (int i = 0; i < numArcs; ++i)
        {
            int arc = minCostFlow.AddArcWithCapacityAndUnitCost(startNodes[i], endNodes[i],
                                                 capacities[i], unitCosts[i]);
            if (arc != i) throw new Exception("Internal error");
        }

        // Add node supplies.
        for (int i = 0; i < numNodes; ++i)
        {
            minCostFlow.SetNodeSupply(i, supplies[i]);
        }


        //Console.WriteLine("Solving min cost flow with " + numNodes + " nodes, and " +
        //                  numArcs + " arcs, source=" + source + ", sink=" + sink);

        // Find the min cost flow.
        int solveStatus = minCostFlow.Solve();
        if (solveStatus == MinCostFlow.OPTIMAL)
        {
            long optimalCost = minCostFlow.OptimalCost();
            Console.WriteLine("Minimum cost: " + optimalCost);
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine(" Edge   Flow / Capacity  Cost");
            for (int i = 0; i < numArcs; ++i)
            {
                long cost = minCostFlow.Flow(i) * minCostFlow.UnitCost(i);
                Console.WriteLine(minCostFlow.Tail(i) + " -> " +
                                  minCostFlow.Head(i) + "  " +
                                  string.Format("{0,3}", minCostFlow.Flow(i)) + "  / " +
                                  string.Format("{0,3}", minCostFlow.Capacity(i)) + "       " +
                                  string.Format("{0,3}", cost));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Solving the min cost flow problem failed. Solver status: " +
                              solveStatus);
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SolveMinCostFlow();
        Console.Read();
    }
```

But I get error: Solving the min cost flow problem failed. Solver status: 4
What am I doing wrong here? I suppose there should be something with defining parameters at the start of SolveMinCostFlow but can't figure it out.

Comment: What does is the solveStatus value when you fail?  It is not Optimal, but what is returned?

Comment: solveStatus value is 4 when it fails

Comment: What is the name of the enumeration name for solveStatus = 4?  (something like Optimal?  Since it is a positive number it is probably not an error, just not Optimal.

Comment: Should supplies not be something like `[700,800,-500,-600,-400]`?

Comment: What are capacities then and unit costs? But yeah, it makes sense.

Comment: No arc capacities. The unit cost are obvious.

Comment: When I put array of 0s to capacities array I get another error. Number 3 which is INFEASIBLE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To summarize: a balanced n x m transportation problem can be converted to a max flow problem using or-tools as follows:

- n + m nodes with supply and demand (demand modeled as negative supply)
- n * m arcs with infinite capacity and costs c(i,j)

Some python code to verify this:

```
from ortools.graph import pywrapgraph

#           A1      A2      A3      Supply
# T1        0       600     100     700
# T2        500     0       300     800
# Demand    500     600     400

numNodes = 5
numArcs = 6;
startNodes = [ 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1 ]
endNodes = [ 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4 ]
capacities =  [9999] * numArcs
unitCosts =  [0, 600, 100, 500, 0, 300 ]
supplies = [700,800,-500,-600,-400]

# Instantiate a SimpleMinCostFlow solver.
min_cost_flow = pywrapgraph.SimpleMinCostFlow()

# Add each arc.
for i in range(0, len(startNodes)):
    min_cost_flow.AddArcWithCapacityAndUnitCost(startNodes[i], endNodes[i],
                                                capacities[i], unitCosts[i])

# Add node supplies.
for i in range(0, len(supplies)):
    min_cost_flow.SetNodeSupply(i, supplies[i])


# Find the minimum cost flow 
if min_cost_flow.Solve() == min_cost_flow.OPTIMAL:
    print('Minimum cost:', min_cost_flow.OptimalCost())
    print('')
    print('  Arc    Flow / Capacity  Cost')
    for i in range(min_cost_flow.NumArcs()):
      cost = min_cost_flow.Flow(i) * min_cost_flow.UnitCost(i)
      print('%1s -> %1s   %3s  / %3s       %3s' % (
          min_cost_flow.Tail(i),
          min_cost_flow.Head(i),
          min_cost_flow.Flow(i),
          min_cost_flow.Capacity(i),
          cost))
else:
    print('There was an issue with the min cost flow input.')
```

This prints:

```
Minimum cost: 80000

  Arc    Flow / Capacity  Cost
0 -> 2   500  / 9999         0
0 -> 3     0  / 9999         0
0 -> 4   200  / 9999       20000
1 -> 2     0  / 9999         0
1 -> 3   600  / 9999         0
1 -> 4   200  / 9999       60000
```

More interesting is a non-balanced transportation problem with sum supply > sum demand. Or-tools min-cost-flow algorithm can handle that also (via `min_cost_flow.SolveMaxFlowWithMinCost()`).

Answer (score 2):

sorry but I believe that it would be better to add a sink and modify the capacities of the main network. This modification would allow you to optimize your current data and meet the specific requirements.

```
#           A1      A2      A3      Supply
# T1        0       600     100     700  
# T2        500     0       300     800  
# Demand    500     600     400

numNodes = 6
numArcs = 9;
startNodes = [ 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1] + [2,3,4]
endNodes = [ 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4 ]+ [5,5,5 ]
capacities =  [0,1000,1000,1000,0,1000]+[500,600,400]
unitCosts =  [0, 600, 100, 500, 0, 300 ]+[0,0,0]
supplies = [700,800,0,0,0,-1500]
```

So by adding the extra node (sink) you are making sure your demands are met, and by changing the capacities you make sure you do not send units to the node with a cost unit of 0 ( I assume the cero means nothing goes to that node from that specific source). Hope it helps !
Output:
    Costo Minimo: 710000

```
  Ruta    Flujo / Capacidad  Costo
0 -> 2     0  /   0         0
0 -> 3   600  / 1000       360000
0 -> 4   100  / 1000       10000
1 -> 2   500  / 1000       250000
1 -> 3     0  /   0         0
1 -> 4   300  / 1000       90000
2 -> 5   500  / 500         0
3 -> 5   600  / 600         0
4 -> 5   400  / 400         0


Where costo minimo = minimum cost
```